# What does $P$ stand for in a logit regression

Tags: logistic, econometrics, logit

I was reading this paper:

http://landdevelopability.org/ChiWebPublications/Chi%20and%20Voss%202005_JRAP_Migration%20Decision%20Making.pdf

and on page 7, they say that

$\ln(\frac{P}{1-P})=\text{some function}$.

However, it's not entirely clear what $P$ is (in fact, I don't think it's ever stated explicitly).

Since this is a logit regression, is $P$ just some probability that (in this case) the person moves? If so, wouldn't $P$ need to be more explicit (i.e. the probability the person moves within, say, 1 month). Does that make sense in this context? If not, what the heck is $P$?

Comment: It's the "success" probability of a binary random variable.  Usually it's specific to an individual, and the right hand side is a function of that person's characteristics.

Comment: If this is a success probability, then wouldn't we need more info? Success probability of what? Presumably the probability the person moves...but that doesn't say much..is it in the last year, the last month, etc.. I'm not sure it's specified in the paper, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Reading the paper, P appears to be probability of moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multivariate logit regression model. For some binary variable $Y$, $P$ is defined in this instance as $P(Y=1)$, while $1-P$ would be $P(Y=0)$.  This gives us a measure of "odds", and the expression $\ln(\frac{P}{1-P})$ gives us the log of the odds, or the log odds.

See [this page](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/odds_ratio.htm) for more information and logic on how it is calculated.

Therefore, in your specific case, $Y$ would whether or not the person moves, with $P$ being the probability of moving, and $1-P$ being the probability of not moving.  Referring to your comment, the information on timeframe etc. is not captured in this variable, it is simply whether or not the person moves.  In your regression model, you can look at the effects of these different variables and see if they matter.

A more formal definition of what your outcome variable is should be stated somewhere in the paper, but with a quick glance I can't find it.

As a note, usually it's best practice to put the pertinent section from the paper in the text of the question, as sometimes papers are removed from servers and people won't be able to see what you were referring too.  It also allows people to quickly skim your question and answer.

Comment: Shouldn't this read Pr(Y=1) and Pr(Y=0)?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov You mean referring to probability of $Y=1$ and $Y=0$? My professors have gone back and forth between $Pr()$ and $P()$ for the probability function, and I've just generally stuck to the $P()$ notation.  Is either way correct?

Comment: My main concern is whether the equals parts should be inside the parentheses.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Whoops, good catch. Sorry about that, wrote the answer very quickly and didn't pay attention to what I was actually saying. Thanks, edited!